# How to properly apply decltype together with SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, decltype

I wrote a template wrapper that should find out if the class owns the function.

```
template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename ,typename = void>
struct has_member:std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct has_member<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back())>>:std::true_type{};
```

But I can't figure out how to apply it correctly.I tried at first like this:

```
template<typename T, bool = has_member<T>::value>
void foo(T& container) {
    std::cout << "i here";
}
```

But everything goes there, i.e. even if there is no push_back function:

```
std::set<int> st;
foo(st); // okey
```

Tried to change to:

```
template<typename T,typename std::enable_if_t< has_member<T>::value ,int>* = nullptr >
void foo(T& container) {
    std::cout << "i here";
}
```

But together with such a function call

```
std::vector<int> vc(10);
foo(vc);
```

I get a few errors:

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "foo" matches the argument list    
Error   C2672   'foo': no matching overloaded function found    
Error   C2783   'void foo(T &)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
```

I'd happy some help to figure out what I did wrong .

Also.
Can all structures be replaced with?

```
template<typename T>
using has_type = decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back());
```

I also did not get an insert in the function (with the same errors as above)

Comment: *But then I get a few errors:* This is the expected behavior. What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: @songyuanyao I use a vector there and expected that it will pass

Comment: There is no `std::vector::push_back()` overload with no function parameters.

Comment: in addition to the issue in the answer, there is no SFINAE on `foo`, you either need to specialize it based on value of `has_member` or actually apply SFINAE on it. Currently it just gets a `bool` parameter that is either `true` or `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use a vector there and expected that it will pass

The problem is in `std::declval<T>().push_back()`, there's no `push_back` taking nothing for `std::vector`.

You need to pass argument to `push_back`, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct has_member<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(std::declval<typename T::value_type>()))>>:std::true_type{};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RcqTKhyTU7l5WuDg)

And about why the 1st solution doesn't work, because when `has_member<T>::value` is `true`, the instantiation `foo<T, true>` gets called, otherwise `foo<T, false>` gets called, both are valid.

Comment: Indeed, I did not even think that you need to take into account the parameters . Thank you for your help!